# I am creating an app and using search View

Tags: android, android-custom-view

I am creating an app and using Search View with custom list adapter when I am searching any text then it showing black dialog box with searching text but I want to remove this black dialog box and another issue is when I am selecting any record it selecting record according to original list please help me as soon as possible.

```
 private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private TextView name_textView, f_name_textView, m_name_textView,
            h_number_textView;
    private ArrayList<SeccUserListAdapterBean> list;
    private ArrayList<SeccUserListAdapterBean> list1;

    public SeccUserListAdapter(Context context,
            ArrayList<SeccUserListAdapterBean> list) {
        super();
        this.list = list;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @SuppressLint("InflateParams")
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (convertView == null)
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.seccuserlistlayout, null);
        name_textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        f_name_textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        m_name_textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        h_number_textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView4);
        name_textView.setText(list.get(position).getBen_name());
        f_name_textView.setText(list.get(position).getBen_fname());
        m_name_textView.setText(list.get(position).getBen_gender());
        h_number_textView.setText(list.get(position).getBen_house_no());

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return new Filter() {

            @SuppressLint("DefaultLocale")
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                final FilterResults oReturn = new FilterResults();
                final ArrayList<SeccUserListAdapterBean> results = new ArrayList<SeccUserListAdapterBean>();

                if (list1 == null)
                    list1 = list;
                if (constraint != null) {
                    if (list1 != null && list1.size() > 0) {
                        for (final SeccUserListAdapterBean family : list1) {
                            if (family
                                    .getBen_name()
                                    .toLowerCase()
                                    .contains(
                                            constraint.toString().toLowerCase()))
                                results.add(family);
                        }
                    }
                    oReturn.values = results;
                }
                return oReturn;
            }

            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,
                    FilterResults results) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                list = (ArrayList<SeccUserListAdapterBean>) results.values;
                notifyDataSetChanged();

            }

        };
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For the second part of your question. you can set a click listener to your listview and get the view for selected row. Then pass the position of the object to your adapter's `getItem(int position)` method.

```
ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.myList);

lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long i) 
            {
                  // Get the item here. use the adapter's getItem() method

                 YourObject obj = (YourObject) adapter.getItem(position);
                 // Do whatever with your object.


            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
```

I don't think you are using the standard SearchView from the android SDK. If using a different library see the documentation for it.

Comment: Thanks for giving immediate response.... if you know my first questions answer then I would be highly thankful to you...how can i remove this dialog with searching text